# is 404 error being handling by default in catch , and why I can't pass throw error message to catch?

Tags: javascript, api

I'm trying to pass the `request.status` to the catch but it still showing 
failed to fetch. Here's my code:

```
let url = "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json"; 

fetch(url).then(function(request){ 
  if(!request.ok){ 
     throw Error(request.status); 
   } else { 
     return request; 
   } 
}).then(function(response) { 
    console.log("ok"); 
}).catch(function(error) { 
    console.log(error); 
});
```